# C# REST API Getting Error while creating new record(Insert)

Tags: community

I am using REST API in C# to create new record in the Custom Object.

But it throw an error. I verified that field exists on the object.

//Error Message
//[{ "message":"Unable to create/update fields: Name.
//Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.",
//"errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE","fields":["Name"]}]

This is how my Custom App policy looks like

[image]

Here is the code

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RowData);

```
        HttpContent contentCreate = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        string uri = $"{serviceURL}{ApiEndpoint}sobjects/{Object.SalesObjectName}";

        HttpRequestMessage requestCreate = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
        requestCreate.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
        requestCreate.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        requestCreate.Content = contentCreate;

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestCreate).Result;
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data type of the `Name` field on the object is Auto-Number, then you can't use the field in an insert or update operation.

Comment: yes, that field turned out to be AutoNumber